A bound for average integral.
Let $p\in(1,\infty)$, $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)\cap L^p(\mathbb R)$, $I_n=[0,2^{-n}\ ]$ for $n\in\mathbb N$, and suppose $f$ has the compact support. Then, is there exist $M>0$ that is independent of $n$ and satisfies $\displaystyle \left|\frac{1}{|I_n|}\int_{I_n}f(t)\, dt \right|\leqq M\ $  ?
My try is $\displaystyle \left|\frac{1}{|I_n|}\int_{I_n}f(t)\, dt \right|\leqq \frac{1}{|I_n|}\int_{I_n}|f(t)|\, dt \leqq
\frac{1}{|I_n|}\int_{I_n}\sup_{t\in I_n}|f(t)|\, dt=\sup_{t\in I_n}|f(t)|
$, but is this bounded by some constant that is independent of $n$ ?

Maybe try to use Hölder inequality to obtain $\int_{I_n} |f| \leq \left|f\right|{L^p(I_n)} \left|1\right|{L^q(I_n)}$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1,$ then you see why $f \in L^p$ is assumed?

Then I get
$|I_n|^{-1}\int_{I_n}|f|\leqq |I_n|^{-1+1/q}\quad(\int_{I_n} |f(t)|^p, dt)^{1/p}=|I_n|^{-1/p}\quad(\int_\mathbb{R} 1_{I_n} (t)|f(t)|^p, dt)^{1/p}\quad $ and how should I use $f\in L^p$ ? @F_M_
